# Why does a MySQL query with a Dependent Subquery take so much longer to execute than executing each statement individually?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm running two queries.

The first one gets unique IDs. This executes in ~350ms.

```
select parent_id
from duns_match_sealed_air_072815
group by duns_number
```

Then I paste those IDs into this second query. With >10k ids pasted in, it also executes in about ~350ms.

```
select term, count(*) as count
from companies, business_types, business_types_to_companies
where
    business_types.id = business_types_to_companies.term_id
    and companies.id = business_types_to_companies.company_id
    and raw_score > 25
    and diversity = 1
    and company_id in (paste,ten,thousand,ids,here)
group by term
order by count desc;
```

When I combine these queries into one it takes a long time to execute. I don't know how long because I stopped it after minutes.

```
select term, count(*) as count
from companies, business_types, business_types_to_companies
where
    business_types.id = business_types_to_companies.term_id
    and companies.id = business_types_to_companies.company_id
    and raw_score > 25
    and diversity = 1
    and company_id in (
        select parent_id
        from duns_match_sealed_air_072815
        group by duns_number
    )
group by term
order by count desc;
```

What is going on?

Comment: you'd probably be better off rewriting as a JOIN anyways.

Comment: Yes, I use joins to perform this kind of thing as embedded queries do tend to be slower - I was under the impression that it runs the subquery for each record it retrieves for `SELECT term, count*`, but as @MarcB pointed out this may not be the case.

Comment: Which table is `term` in?  `raw_score`?  Etc.  Please use the `JOIN...ON` format for joins.

Answer (score 1):

It's down to the way it processes the query - I believe it has to run your embedded query once for each row, whereas using two queries allows you to store the result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: probably not, since the subquery isn't using anything from the parent query.

Answer (score 1):

The query has been re-written using `JOIN`, but particularly I've used `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. This is a short in the dark. It is possible that there may be many values generated in the sub-query causing the outer query to struggle while it goes through matching each item returned from the sub-query.

```
select term, count(*) as count
from companies c
inner join business_types_to_companies bc on bc.company_id = c.id
inner join business_types b on b.id = bc.term_id
where 
    raw_score > 25
    and diversity = 1
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from duns_match_sealed_air_072815
        where parent_id = c.id
    )
group by term
order by count desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, with respect, your subquery doesn't use `GROUP BY` in a sensible way.

```
select parent_id         /* wrong GROUP BY */
  from duns_match_sealed_air_072815
 group by duns_number
```

In fact, it misuses the pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html . I can't tell what your application logic intends from this query, but I can tell you that it actually returns an unpredictably selected `parent_id` value associated with each distinct `duns_number` value.

Do you want

```
select MIN(parent_id) parent_id  
  from duns_match_sealed_air_072815
 group by duns_number
```

or something like that? That one selects the lowest parent ID associated with each given number.

Sometimes MySQL has a hard time optimizing the `WHERE .... IN ()` query pattern.  Try a join instead. Like this:

```
select term, count(*) as count
  from companies
  join (
          select MIN(parent_id) parent_id
            from duns_match_sealed_air_072815
           group by duns_number
       ) idlist ON companies.id = idlist.parent_id
  join business_types_to_companies ON companies.id = business_types_to_companies.company_id
  join business_types ON business_types.id = business_types_to_companies.term_id
 where raw_score > 25
   and diversity = 1
 group by term 
 order by count desc
```

To optimize this further we'll need to see the table definitions and the output from [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html).

Comment: Great point and thanks for the feedback. I know that `group by` on this specific query returns an ambiguous parent_id, and it doesn't matter for my application.

Comment: Compliant GROUP BY subqueries may be easier for the query planner to handle.